# Is it possible to use lapply() (or some other command) with multiple list object inputs in r?

Tags: r, iteration, lapply

I want to use `lapply()` with multiple list inputs.

Specifically, I want to run `lm()` tests that different IVs, DVs, and datasets.

I created 2 datasets, called `diamonds_top300` and `diamonds_bottom300`, derived from the `ggplot2::diamonds` dataset. I wanted to run `lm()` tests on these datasets, where the IVs were `x` or `y` and the DVs were `price` or `carat`.

I could do it the long way, using the code below:

```
## long way
# ---- NOTE: works

### DV is price, IV is x, and dataset is diamonds_top300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_price__IV_is_x <-
  lm(price ~ x, data = diamonds_top300)

### DV is price, IV is y, and dataset is diamonds_top300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_price__IV_is_y <-
  lm(price ~ y, data = diamonds_top300)

### DV is carat, IV is x, and dataset is diamonds_top300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_x <-
  lm(carat ~ x, data = diamonds_top300)

### DV is carat, IV is y, and dataset is diamonds_top300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_y <-
  lm(carat ~ y, data = diamonds_top300)

### DV is price, IV is x, and dataset is diamonds_bottom300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_price__IV_is_x <-
  lm(price ~ x, data = diamonds_bottom300)

### DV is price, IV is y, and dataset is diamonds_bottom300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_price__IV_is_y <-
  lm(price ~ y, data = diamonds_bottom300)

### DV is carat, IV is x, and dataset is diamonds_bottom300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_x <-
  lm(carat ~ x, data = diamonds_bottom300)

### DV is carat, IV is y, and dataset is diamonds_bottom300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_y <-
  lm(carat ~ y, data = diamonds_bottom300)
```

When I tried to do it the short way, using the `lapply()` code below, but this did not work. I wanted to do this using 3 list inputs (i.e., one for the data set used, one for DVs used, and one for IVs used).

```
## short way, using lapply()
# ---- NOTE: does not work

### creates list object
lm__dataset_is_XXXX__DV_is_XXXX__IV_is_XXXX <- 
  lapply(
    # ---- NOTE: tells dataset used in analysis
    DV_info$dataset_analyses,
    # ---- NOTE: tells DV used in analysis
    DV_info$DV_original,
    # ---- NOTE: tells IV used in analysis
    IV_info$IV_original,
    function(
      # ---- NOTE: name of function object input for dataset used in lapply() object
      dataset_list,
      # ---- NOTE: name of function object input for DV used in lapply() object
      DV_list,
      # ---- NOTE: name of function object input for IV used in lapply() object
      IV_list
             ) {
      # ---- NOTE: creates _funct_object versions of function() inputs
      IV_funct_object <- 
        IV_list
      DV_funct_object <- 
        DV_list
      dataset_funct_object <- 
        dataset_list
      # ---- NOTE: creates 
      lm_funct_object <- 
        lm(DV_funct_object ~ IV_funct_object, data = dataset_funct_object)
      # ---- NOTE: returns object
      return(lm_funct_object)
    }
  )

### changes list object name
lm__dataset_is_XXXX__DV_is_XXXX__IV_is_XXXX <- 
  setNames(
    lm__dataset_is_XXXX__DV_is_XXXX__IV_is_XXXX, 
    paste(
      "list_derived_object_",
      "lm",
      "_dataset_is",
      DV_info$dataset_analyses,
      "_DV_is",
      DV_info$DV_original,
      "_IV_is",
      IV_info$IV_original,
      sep = "_"
           )
  )
```

I would like to do this using `lapply()`, if this is possible, since I can then modify the code associated with `lapply()`, but I'm open to other options (e.g., using mapply() with pre-made user-generated functions).

Any advice is very much appreciated.

FYI, I use a 2013 Macbook Pro with a 2.4 GHz dual-core intel chip, 8 GB of ram, macOS big sur 11.2.2, RStudio Version 1.4.1106, and the R Base Package 4.04.

Thanks.

---

---

The R script I used is below:

```
#### lapply() with multiple objects ####




# Loads packages
# ---- NOTE: making plots and diamonds dataset
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}
# ---- NOTE: for data wrangling
if(!require(dplyr)){install.packages("dplyr")}




# dataset creation

## for dataset with top 300 rows
# ---- NOTE: selects only the top 300 rows of the dataset
diamonds_top300 <- data.frame(dplyr::top_n(diamonds, 300, table))
# ---- NOTE: gives dataset info
head(diamonds_top300)
str(diamonds_top300)
colnames(diamonds_top300)
nrow(diamonds_top300)
# ---- NOTE: gives unique values of Fixed and Random effects, and dvs
unique(diamonds_top300$price)
unique(diamonds_top300$y)
unique(diamonds_top300$cut)
unique(diamonds_top300$color)
unique(diamonds_top300$carat)
unique(diamonds_top300$clarity)
unique(diamonds_top300$depth)
unique(diamonds_top300$table)

## for dataset with bottom 300 rows
### dataset
# ---- NOTE: selects only the bottom 300 rows of the dataset
diamonds_bottom300 <- data.frame(dplyr::top_n(diamonds, -300, table))
# ---- NOTE: gives dataset info
head(diamonds_bottom300)
str(diamonds_bottom300)
colnames(diamonds_bottom300)
nrow(diamonds_bottom300)
# ---- NOTE: gives unique values of Fixed and Random effects, and dvs
unique(diamonds_bottom300$price)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$y)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$cut)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$color)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$carat)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$clarity)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$depth)
unique(diamonds_bottom300$table)

## creates DV_info object
# ---- NOTE: length of data needs to match up with the maximum number of tests being done (i.e., 8 tests total means this list based data frame needs to be 8 rows in length)
DV_info <- 
  data.frame(
    DV_original = c("price", "carat", "price", "carat", "price", "carat", "price", "carat"),
    dataset_analyses = c("diamonds_top300", "diamonds_top300", "diamonds_top300", "diamonds_top300", "diamonds_bottom300", "diamonds_bottom300", "diamonds_bottom300")
  )

## creates IV_info object
# ---- NOTE: length of data needs to match up with the maximum number of tests being done (i.e., 8 tests total means this list based data frame needs to be 8 rows in length)
IV_info <- 
  data.frame(
    IV_original = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y")
  )




# creating lm() objects

## long way
# ---- NOTE: works

### DV is price, IV is x, and dataset is diamonds_top300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_price__IV_is_x <-
  lm(price ~ x, data = diamonds_top300)

### DV is price, IV is y, and dataset is diamonds_top300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_price__IV_is_y <-
  lm(price ~ y, data = diamonds_top300)

### DV is carat, IV is x, and dataset is diamonds_top300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_x <-
  lm(carat ~ x, data = diamonds_top300)

### DV is carat, IV is y, and dataset is diamonds_top300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_y <-
  lm(carat ~ y, data = diamonds_top300)

### DV is price, IV is x, and dataset is diamonds_bottom300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_price__IV_is_x <-
  lm(price ~ x, data = diamonds_bottom300)

### DV is price, IV is y, and dataset is diamonds_bottom300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_price__IV_is_y <-
  lm(price ~ y, data = diamonds_bottom300)

### DV is carat, IV is x, and dataset is diamonds_bottom300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_x <-
  lm(carat ~ x, data = diamonds_bottom300)

### DV is carat, IV is y, and dataset is diamonds_bottom300
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_y <-
  lm(carat ~ y, data = diamonds_bottom300)

### lists created file(s)
# ---- NOTE: list of object, out right
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_price__IV_is_x
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_price__IV_is_y
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_x
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_top300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_y
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_price__IV_is_x
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_price__IV_is_y
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_x
lm__dataset_is_diamonds_bottom300__DV_is_carat__IV_is_y
# ---- NOTE: apropos() command list
apropos("lm__dataset_is_")

## short way, using lapply()
# ---- NOTE: does not work

### creates list object
lm__dataset_is_XXXX__DV_is_XXXX__IV_is_XXXX <- 
  lapply(
    # ---- NOTE: tells dataset used in analysis
    DV_info$dataset_analyses,
    # ---- NOTE: tells DV used in analysis
    DV_info$DV_original,
    # ---- NOTE: tells IV used in analysis
    IV_info$IV_original,
    function(
      # ---- NOTE: name of function object input for dataset used in lapply() object
      dataset_list,
      # ---- NOTE: name of function object input for DV used in lapply() object
      DV_list,
      # ---- NOTE: name of function object input for IV used in lapply() object
      IV_list
             ) {
      # ---- NOTE: creates _funct_object versions of function() inputs
      IV_funct_object <- 
        IV_list
      DV_funct_object <- 
        DV_list
      dataset_funct_object <- 
        dataset_list
      # ---- NOTE: creates 
      lm_funct_object <- 
        lm(DV_funct_object ~ IV_funct_object, data = dataset_funct_object)
      # ---- NOTE: returns object
      return(lm_funct_object)
    }
  )

### changes list object name
lm__dataset_is_XXXX__DV_is_XXXX__IV_is_XXXX <- 
  setNames(
    lm__dataset_is_XXXX__DV_is_XXXX__IV_is_XXXX, 
    paste(
      "list_derived_object_",
      "lm",
      "_dataset_is",
      DV_info$dataset_analyses,
      "_DV_is",
      DV_info$DV_original,
      "_IV_is",
      IV_info$IV_original,
      sep = "_"
           )
  )
```

Comment: Your sample `DV_info` seems to have a mismatch in the number of rows for your two columns. One has 7, one has 8. Since you are trying to iterate multiple lists, you really should be using `mapply`. If you insist on using `lapply`, you'd be better off iterating over an index value that you could use to subset all your various values. you can't use variables in formula, only column names. Look at functions like `reformulate` to turn stings into formulas. Also note that you can't just interchange literal character values and variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `Map` -

```
Map(function(x, y, z) lm(reformulate(x, y), data = z),
  IV_info$IV_original, DV_info$DV_original, mget(DV_info$dataset_analyses))
```

Comment: And `Map` is wrapper to `mapply` (elementwise loop).

Answer (score 1):

Consider building all combinations of your inputs with `expand.grid`, then call `Map` with `reformulate` to dynamically build formula from strings and `get` to retrieve object by character name.

```r
run_model <- function(dv, iv, data)
    lm(reformulate(iv, dv), data=get(data))

inputs <- expand.grid(
    dv = c("price", "carat"),
    iv = c("x", "y"),
    data = c("diamonds_bottom300", "diamonds_top300")
)

lm_results <- Map(run_model, inputs$dv, inputs$iv, inputs$data)
# EQUIVALENTLY:
lm_results <- mapply(run_model, inputs$dv, inputs$iv, inputs$data, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```